# Revoke access to devise-jwt on Denylist strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-jwt

I am using devise-jwt gem, from what I see on the wrapped gem https://github.com/waiting-for-dev/warden-jwt_auth
there is a static method `revoke_jwt(payload, user)`
I want to write a script that will revoke access on a specific user, what will be the payload in this case?

Answer (score -2):

If you are using denylist you should add the jti value to the denylist table on revoke.
[Look at mine.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvVZ8.png)

Comment: Why on earth would you post a picture of your code?!? Please paste the actual code. I can't believe a moderator didn't step in.

Comment: Sorry mate, i was in active